# Non-type template parameter: pass to another method

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have this generic class with a single, non-type template parameter:

```
template<uint8_t D>
class Tile
{
private:
    uint8_t density = D;

public:
    void someMethod()
    {
        if(D == 1)
        { /* do this */ }
        else
        { /* do that */ }
    }
};
```

Depending on the template parameter `D`, a specific code path is taken in the object's methods. The reason to do it like this, for me, is that this enables the compiler to optimize away the `if` statement altogether, since `D` never changes. To the outside world, the template parameter `D` doesn't change the object's interface at all - no matter what value `D` has, the object's interface stays the same.

Now I want to pass such an object to another method, to do something with it. How exactly would I do that in a general way?

```
void processSomething(Tile *tile)
{
    tile->someMethod();
}
```

This fails of course, since the template parameter was not specified. For the users of `Tile` however, the template parameter doesn't make any difference, it is for internal state only. How can I write `processSomething`, so that the value of the template parameter doesn't matter?

The only solutions I found were to either implement overloads like this:

```
void processSomething(Tile<0> *tile);
void processSomething(Tile<1> *tile);
...
```

which is impractical. Or to make `processSomething` a template itself, but then I'd have to specify the value to calls to `processSomething`, which only shifts the problem to the caller.

Comment: Base class? ---

Comment: I'd also like to avoid inheritance because of performance concerns (in the real project, the `someMethod` is called very, very often)

Comment: Do you really need Tile to be template ? you store its value as member...

Comment: There'd be no performance issue at all. Which function is called is determined at compile time.

Comment: Be it through inheritance-based polymorphism or otherwise, you will have to have some kind of dynamic dispatch here. If your function's signature is just `processSomething(Tile *tile)`, then it has no idea of what `D` is and can only choose a branch at runtime. Hence the template solution, which *can* generate two statically-dispatched versions. Long story short: you have to choose the point where you trade genericity for performance.

Comment: How about [if constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) from C++17 standard?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why making `processSomething` a template will force you to specify the value in all calls to it. I made a small proof of concept based on you code and then the compiler was able to deduce which processSomething to use from the parameter.

Comment: Further examination: is `someMethod` called often on the same object, on a batch of identical (wrt. `D`) objects, or on a batch of heterogeneous objects? Maybe CPU branch prediction has solved your problem already, or you could restructure your code to use batching and factoring out the branch as an optimization.

Comment: The motivation behind all this is that `someMethod` is called very often (millions of times per second), so squeezing every last bit of performance out of it is worthwile. I'm trying to get rid of the `if` conditional, which I believe the compiler is only able to optimize away if I make it a template value parameter. If I make D a mere member of `Tile`, the compiler can't know which value D has and has to leave the `if` in. At least that's what I'm expecting. I could also use inheritance, but then I'd have a `vtable` lookup.

Comment: @Johan: you're right, as I learned now I don't have to specify the values to calls to `processSomething`. The compiler is able to infer it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write another template for the function:

```
template<uint8_t D>
void processSomething(Tile<D> *tile)
{
    tile->someMethod();
}
```

Comment: True, but then I'd have to call it like this: `processSomething<0>(tile)`, `processSomething<1>(tile)` etc., right?

Comment: No, the good thing about function templates is that, compiler automatically infers the types. In other words, you can call just call by:  processSomething(tile)

Comment: This was a way simpler question than I expected.

Answer (score 3):

`Tile<0>` is a completely different class than `Tile<1>`. You err in assuming that there is some relationship between instantiations of templates on different parameters.

The fact that *you* know that there is no difference in internal representation is irrelevant to the compiler. If you want polymorphic behavior, you need polymorphic classes.

Comment: It's true, they are different classes, but I know that the interface doesn't change with the template value. All I'm wondering is if there is a way to express this in C++.

Comment: The point is, the interface *is* different with template parameters. Consider that std::pair<int, float> is completely different from std::pair<Foo, Bar>. Just because they instantiate the same template does not make them related classes.

Comment: The way to express that in C++ is to make your function templated also, so it can take different types.